# How can I load a css file from a static folder?

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I can´t load a css file in the Header of my home.hsb (Handlebars) Template.
I'm using node.js with express for the backend.
Maybe I set the path wrong, but I don´t know what the failure is.

Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong?

My folder structure:

```
public
  -> home.css
  -> login.css
  -> signup.css

src
  -> index.js

templates
  -> home.hbs
  -> login.hbs
  -> signup.hbs
  -> user.hbs
```

index.js:

```
const express=require("express")
const app=express()
const PORT = 80;
const path=require("path")
const hbs=require("hbs")
const collection=require("./mongodb")
const templatePath=path.join(__dirname, '../templates')

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const sessions = require('express-session');

//serving public file
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

app.use(express.json())
app.set("view engine","hbs")
app.set("views",templatePath)
//app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))


// creating 24 hours from milliseconds
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

//session middleware
app.use(sessions({
    secret: "thisismysecrctekeyfhrgfgrfrty84fwir767",
    saveUninitialized:true,
    cookie: { maxAge: oneDay },
    resave: false
}));

// parsing the incoming data
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// cookie parser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

//username and password
const myusername = 'user1'
const mypassword = 'mypassword' 

// a variable to save a session
var session;

app.get("/",(req,res) => {
//    session=req.session;
//    if(session.userid){
//        res.send("Welcome User <a href=\'/logout'>click to logout</a>");
//    }else
 res.render("home")
});
```

home.hbs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    <title>my travel</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Hamburger Menue-->
<div id="hamburger" class="hamburger-icon-container">
  <span class="hamburger-icon">hgfhgf</span>
</div> 
<p>Test</p>
<div id="test"></div>

<h1>Seite wo alle Bilder angezeigt werden</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

My Path to the static folder "public" seems wrong, but i dont know why?

Comment: I think you should use `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` rather than `__dirname + 'public'`.

Comment: Yes you right. I need to include `path.join` statement. But the path should be `path.join(__dirname, '../public')`, i think because the root folder is the `src` folder, where the `index.js` starts. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the leading slash before the `home.css` in your `href`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/home.css">
```

The leading slash `/` indicates that the path should start from the root of your application. This way, the browser will look for the `home.css` file directly in the `public` directory.

And @76484 is right about `path.join`

you should do something like this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

To ensure the correct path is used when serving static files with Express, it's recommended to use the `path.join()` function to concatenate the directory paths. `path.join()` ensures that the correct path separator is used based on the operating system. By using `path.join()`, you can avoid potential issues related to the concatenation of directory paths and ensure a consistent and accurate path for serving static files.

Comment: with `path.join(__dirname, '../public')` it works. Thank you.